# Change value of Enumerator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration, enumerators

I have this code in irb:

```
2.2.1 :001 > a = 0
=> 0 
2.2.1 :002 > b = (a..a+6).step(3)
=> #<Enumerator: 0..6:step(3)> 
2.2.1 :004 > puts b.inspect
#<Enumerator: 0..6:step(3)>
=> nil 
2.2.1 :005 > a = 1
=> 1 
2.2.1 :007 > puts b.inspect
#<Enumerator: 0..6:step(3)>
=> nil
```

What I want to achieve is to change the value of `a` with every iteration, but `a` stays with the same value, worse, Ruby just changes the value of `a` to 0. Is there a way to declare dynamic Enumerators?, ones that change values every time I change the values of my variables?
Thank you.

Comment: do you mean you want b to change whenever a changes?

Comment: Exactly! is that possible?

Comment: You could do something like this `@a = 0; def b(x=@a); (x..x+6).step(3); end`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was doing, it works, thank you @Santhosh

Comment: *"change the value of a with every iteration"* - are you trying to enumerate a specific sequence of numbers? If so, please show the expected result. Maybe there's another way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `b = (a..a+6).step(3)` the expression is evaluated to roughly this: `b = (0..6).step(3)`. Changing `a` after this line, won't change `b`. If you want to change `b` you need to somehow reassign it , the simplest way is after you had changed `a` to 1 repeat the assignment `b = (a..a+6).step(3)`

Comment: Thank you davidrac, I'm resorting to a function like the one Santosh pointed at.